# Crash with GoogleMaps on Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I use GoogleMaps lib on my application since a long time but since I updated Xcode with Swift 4, when I go to the map, my application crash.

Error :

> WARNING: Unable to find and load 'GoogleMaps.bundle' for Google Maps SDK for iOS. This may be a sign that you've forgotten to include a resources bundle in your 'Copy Bundle Resources' build phase. As this bundle contains important resources, you may encounter missing images, translations and other incorrect behavior.

Why ?

Comment: Are you using the new build system? It has caused me problems with CocoaPods. Might be related to [CP#7209](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/7209).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same issue.
just delete GoogleMaps folder in Pods project,and then "pod install" again.

Comment: Nup its not working i have also cleaned the project too , any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue. just clean the Build: (Window Button)Command + alt option + Shift + K then run the project. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Xcode, Click on Project Navigator In that  goto Pods section 
 `Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps.` folder.
Inside Maps folder you can find 2 folder like `Framework` and `resources`.
Goto `resources` folder you can find

```
GoogleMaps.bundle
```

just drag into Project -> Target -> Build Phases -> `Copy Bundle Resources` selection.

while draping it will ask  Copy items into destination group’s folder is not selected.